# Bootstrap purr alert message should not dismiss automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Am using [Bootstrap-Purr](https://github.com/softwarespot/jquery-bootstrap-purr)  for alert messaging.  By using this, alert message appears and automatically disappears within few seconds. This should not happen. Alert message should be dismissed on only clicking close button, until then it should be viewed.

Tried a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Y3d3D/225/)

```
$.bootstrapPurr('<strong>My error Mesasge </strong> ,Try Again !', {
    type: 'danger',
    delayPause: true,
    align: 'center',
    allow_dismiss: false,
    allowDismissType: 'click',
    draggable: false,
    width:'350px',
    position:'absolute',
    top:'50px',
});
```

Any Idea will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the 'delay' attribute to 0, thats all it will work

```
$.bootstrapPurr('This is another "purr" that will display until manually closed', {
                type: 'danger',
                align: 'left',
                align: 'center',
                delay: 0,
                stackupSpacing: 30
            });
```

Try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Y3d3D/227/)

Comment: Yes That was awesome ! Thank You  +1